# There are no printable documents related to selected orders in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

**Magento 2.4.6**

After upgrading 2.3.5 -> 2.4.6 I am getting the **There are no printable documents related to selected orders** message when I try to print invoices from the order grid. Printing the invoice from the order view directly works though.

Nothing really found on the internet ... any ideas anyone?

Thanks!